# Difference between ELB Protocol and Port number in AWS

Tags: amazon-elb

In ELB setting, we can see HTTP and TCP as protocols for Listeners and I am not sure what would be the difference if I set Listeners as below.

ELB AAA
Load Balancer Protocol: HTTP
Load Balancer Port: 80

ELB BBB
Load Balancer Protocol: TCP
Load Balancer Port: 80

Answer (score 0):

I believe its the same thing HTTP makes use of the TCP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are referring to the older Classic Load Balancer, which has both HTTP and TCP options. The newer ELB generation is segregated more clearly: Application Load Balancer supports only HTTP/HTTPS and Network Load Balancer supports only TCP/UDP.

**Classic Load Balancer**

Refer to this link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-listener-config.html

To understand the difference, you need to understand a little about OSI model Layer 4 and Layer 7.

When configured as HTTP:80, the ELB **terminates** the request. That is, the ELB intercepts the request before forwarding it to the backend over HTTP/TCP. This may seem trivial, but it allows ELB to perform additional features such as sticky sessions.

When configured as TCP:80, the ELB does not intercept the request. It simply forwards the request to the backend with the same set of headers. This is because it *supposedly* operates at the network level, which allows the ELB to be more performant.